# Fusion Table polygon style options - losing style when setting individual polygon via WHERE clause

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

How to set and keep FT Layer polygon style options when setting certain polygons' colour on-click?

Dr Molle kindly helped me out with toggling polygons from a FT, but I want to set the opacity/colour of the initial FT layer polygons - this is easy with

```
styles: [{polygonOptions: {fillOpacity: 0.2,fillColor:"#00FF00",strokeWeight: 1,}}]
```

but as soon as a clicked polygon has its colour set via

```
layer_0.set("styles", [{
  where: "'Postcode district' IN('"+vals.join("','")+"')",
  polygonOptions: {
    fillColor: "#000000"
  }
}]);
```

it resets the 'default' back to the ~50% opacity red.

Below is the altered jsfiddle from Dr.Molle

http://jsfiddle.net/yh2WX/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you overwrite the "styles" property in the click listener, you need to keep the default setting

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9N9p2/1/

```
layer_0.set("styles", [
  {
    polygonOptions: {fillOpacity: 0.2,fillColor:"#00FF00",strokeWeight: 1,}
  },{
    where: "'Postcode district' IN('"+vals.join("','")+"')",
    polygonOptions: {
    fillColor: "#000000"
    }
}]);
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks geocodezip :) (wasn't sure if there was an option I could pass to it, and when I tried to reset the default, I must have got the syntax wrong with too many {} - cheers!)